# Injection Error : Configuration files are not supported. at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor() In Asp .Net5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am programming a .NET project. I have a problem with this project. I have to use a web service that does not have a document. These classes are automatically generated and brought from the old project.

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Nap.Api.Statement.Services.Services {
    
    
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", ConfigurationName="SmartCardService.PKG_RMTO_WSPortType")]
    public interface PKG_RMTO_WSPortType {
        
        // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper name (SVARCHAR2-RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput) of message RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest does not match the default value (RMTO_WEB_SERVICES)
        [OperationContractAttribute(Action="RMTO_WEB_SERVICES", ReplyAction="*")]
        RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse RMTO_WEB_SERVICES(RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest request);
        
        [OperationContractAttribute(Action="RMTO_WEB_SERVICES", ReplyAction="*")]
        Task<RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse> RMTO_WEB_SERVICESAsync(RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest request);
    }
    
    [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="SVARCHAR2-RMTO_WEB_SERVICESInput", WrapperNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", IsWrapped=true)]
    public partial class RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest {
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_USERNAME-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=0)]
        public string IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_SERVICEID-NUMBER-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=1)]
        public double IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PASSWORD-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=2)]
        public string IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_9-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=3)]
        public string IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_8-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=4)]
        public string IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_7-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=5)]
        public string IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_6-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=6)]
        public string IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_5-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=7)]
        public string IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_4-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=8)]
        public string IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_3-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=9)]
        public string IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_2-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=10)]
        public string IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_10-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=11)]
        public string IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN;
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="IN_PARAM_1-VARCHAR2-IN", Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=12)]
        public string IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN;
        
        public RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest() {
        }
        
        public RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest(string IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN, double IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN, string IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN) {
            this.IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN = IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN = IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN;
            this.IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN = IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN;
            this.IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN;
        }
    }
    
    [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="RMTO_WEB_SERVICESOutput", WrapperNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", IsWrapped=true)]
    public partial class RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse {
        
        [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/TR_PUBLIC_WS/PKG_RMTO_WS", Order=0)]
        public string RETURN;
        
        public RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse() {
        }
        
        public RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse(string RETURN) {
            this.RETURN = RETURN;
        }
    }
    
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeChannel : PKG_RMTO_WSPortType, IClientChannel {
    }
    
    [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient : ClientBase<PKG_RMTO_WSPortType>, PKG_RMTO_WSPortType {
        
        public PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient() {
        }
        
        public PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }
        
        public PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }
        
        public PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }
        
        public PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }
        
        [EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse PKG_RMTO_WSPortType.RMTO_WEB_SERVICES(RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.RMTO_WEB_SERVICES(request);
        }
        
        public string RMTO_WEB_SERVICES(string IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN, double IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN, string IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN) {
            RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest inValue = new RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest();
            inValue.IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN = IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN = IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN;
            inValue.IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN = IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN;
            RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse retVal = ((PKG_RMTO_WSPortType)(this)).RMTO_WEB_SERVICES(inValue);
            return retVal.RETURN;
        }
        
        [EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        Task<RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse> PKG_RMTO_WSPortType.RMTO_WEB_SERVICESAsync(RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.RMTO_WEB_SERVICESAsync(request);
        }
        
        public Task<RMTO_WEB_SERVICESResponse> RMTO_WEB_SERVICESAsync(string IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN, double IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN, string IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN, string IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN) {
            RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest inValue = new RMTO_WEB_SERVICESRequest();
            inValue.IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN = IN_USERNAMEVARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN = IN_SERVICEIDNUMBERIN;
            inValue.IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN = IN_PASSWORDVARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_9VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_8VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_7VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_6VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_5VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_4VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_3VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_2VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_10VARCHAR2IN;
            inValue.IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN = IN_PARAM_1VARCHAR2IN;
            return ((PKG_RMTO_WSPortType)(this)).RMTO_WEB_SERVICESAsync(inValue);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to inject this into my startup project. But I can not. The code already exists and is correct: based on Asp MVC

```
container.Register<PKG_RMTO_WSPortType>(() => new PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

I will receive the codes I tested in the new project and the error:

```
    services.TryAddSingleton<PKG_RMTO_WSPortType>(new PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient());
    services.TryAddScoped<PKG_RMTO_WSPortType, PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient>();
```

Error:

> ```
> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Configuration files are not supported.
>    at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
>    at Nap.Api.Statement.Services.Services.PKG_RMTO_WSPortTypeClient..ctor()
> ```
>
> in
> D:\Project\Safar724\Nap.Api.Statement\Layer\Nap.Api.Statement.Services\Connected
> Services\SmartCardService\Reference.cs:line 113
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean
> wrapExceptions)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
> scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method24(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Comment: As far as I know, we couldn't directly copy asp.net codes to the asp.net core they are different. I suggest you could  try to follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide) to re-add the WCF service.